# Lenovo T420 - High CPU load when receiving camera streams from online meetings

Tags: drivers, 18.04, graphics, performance

I have recently switched to Ubuntu from Windows, am pretty new to using desktop Linux, now having 18.04 (Bionic Beaver).

I have noticed that whenever I do online meetings with webcam (tried GoToMeeting, Zoom, Slack - happens with all of them), my CPU cores will be busy around 95% pretty soon (the process of the meeting app), which will make the whole system unusable and really annoying. I have noticed that it only happens, when I receive the webcam video of other people in the meetings.

I have an older notebook (Lenovo T420 extended with 16GB RAM, 512GB SSD) and a good internet connection, but these meetings went smoothly with Windows, so I wonder if my integrated video card is being correctly leveraged or not. From lshw it is:

```
>*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:26 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

> lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

> find /dev -group video
/dev/media0
/dev/video0
/dev/fb0
/dev/dri/card0
/dev/dri/renderD128

>glxinfo | grep -i vendor
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
    Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center (0x8086)
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center

>egrep -i " connected|card detect|primary dev|Setting driver" /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[     8.192] (II) modeset(0): Output LVDS-1 connected
[     8.192] (II) modeset(0): Output HDMI-1 connected
```

Any hint, guidance is welcome. Thanks in advance!